# Cannot Update UIView from Block Code in Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am trying to Update a label for showing the Progress of the File to be downloaded using the **AFNetworking** Framework. The problem is that when i set the percentage to the label in the **setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock**  the label is updated only when the download starts and when download completes.

```
 __weak MTCViewController *weakSelf= self; 
[_operation setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock:^(AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation, NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpected, long long totalBytesReadForFile, long long totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile) {
        float percent = (float)(totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile)*100;;
       // [weakSelf updateProgress:percent];
        [weakSelf updateText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Progress = %f",percent]];
    }];
    [_operation start];
```

Plus when i remove the label update code the block seems to be updating correctly

Comment: are the values of `totalBytesRead` and  `totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile` right?

Comment: One additional point is update ui elements on the main thread only. And what are the values of percent in the entire process.

Comment: @BrunoKoga yes the values are right

Comment: @PraveenS. what if i don't update from main thread.. how can i do that..??

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                              [weakSelf updateText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Progress = %f",percent]];
               
                                 });

Comment: `[weakSelf performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateText:)
                               withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Progress = %f",percent]
                            waitUntilDone:YES]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call all UI changes on the main thread. So, calculate the percentage and then dispatch the code that updates the UI from the main thread:

```
__weak MTCViewController *weakSelf= self; 
[_operation setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock:^(AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation, NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpected, long long totalBytesReadForFile, long long totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile) {
    float percent = ((float)totalBytesRead / (float)totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile)*100;
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [weakSelf updateText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Progress = %f", round(percent)]];
      });
}];
[_operation start];
```

Comment: well using this i get view updated continuously but the percentage calculated is 0.000000 even with the proper values and then suddenly it is 100.0000 after completion.

Comment: try this : float percent = ((float)((int)totalBytesRead) / (float)((int)totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile))*100;

Comment: If you set breakpoints, do you get any values for totalBytesRead and totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile?

Comment: @Marcel you are right but there was just one problem .. i have edited that .. Thanks a Lot